# How is TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV supported on Windows Server?

Tags: tls, windows

According to the last SSL Labs report, everything is green on my server, except support for `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV`.

## Not currently possible with IIS it seems

I've read everywhere that this is not supported on Windows Servers, for example, here:

- Scott Helme, 2015-01-11, *[Getting an A+ on the Qualys SSL Test - Windows Edition](https://scotthelme.co.uk/getting-an-a-on-the-qualys-ssl-test-windows-edition/)*:

> Unfortunately, changes to the Qualys SSL Test since I started writing
>   this article now require TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV support to get an A+
>   rating, but Microsoft has not released support in IIS. This means that
>   all Windows Servers will be capped at an A rating until support is
>   introduced.

## So why does this work for an IIS-using customer of mine?

After spending many hours searching for a solution, I gave up. However, I've recently checked one of my customer's website with SSL Labs report tool and I can see that it is supported :

[image: Downgrade attack prevention]

And it is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard!

I know you can get it supported by disabling TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0, but they are enabled:

[image: Protocol support]

I am not very interested by getting an A+, and I've read that its support is not really needed. I am just very curious about how this Windows Server supports `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` although everyone says it is not possible.

What are the steps to achieve it?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add more links in the question, but the quote comes from here : https://scotthelme.co.uk/getting-an-a-on-the-qualys-ssl-test-windows-edition/, and the "more info" link goes here : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7507/?include_text=1

Comment: The OS might be Windows, but the web server may be Apache, or something else..

Comment: @LamonteCristo : I forgot to mention that the web server is IIS 7.5. Thank you.

Comment: Qualys forum-thread says: [IIS can't do this right now.](https://community.qualys.com/thread/14210) I tend to agree with them and I'm guessing that you're talking to a load balancer in front of the IIS and not the IIS itself.

Comment: @KevinM, did you ever find out?